# Django createsuperuser created admin account with wrong password

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework

I am using django 1.11 and DRF to create an app. When I use `manage.py createsuperuser` command to create a superuser, it successfully created an account for me. But when I am trying to log in to the account. The login screen prompts me a login error.

When I use `manage.py changepassword admin` command to change the password, I can log in to the account.

This is really annoying, and I can't figure out what happened, for days Are there any reason that can cause the command creating a wrong password? :/
Anybody can help?

Answer (score 2):

most probably you have override the create_superuser method you are passing the password in normal text, you should use the set_password method.

```
user.set_password("password")
user.save()
```